# How to cross join and map over a list of values in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have following data frames

```
source

src_id lat long
abcd   123 421
dkna   423 939
ewqm   125 919

dest_id lat long
eakn    110 218
ejkq    819 421
tmvs    491 810
```

I want to evaluate the shortest distance between each src_id and a list of possible destinations. Essentially, I'm trying to take each row from source, evaluate the distance for each row in destination table, taking the minimum value and selecting that dest_id as my selection.

Expected output:

```
src_id lat long dest_id distance
abcd   123 421  eakn    19
dkna   423 939  eakn    12
ewqm   125 919  tmvs    10
```

I'm trying to cross join the tables and then filtering on individual shortest distance, but as the number of rows increase for source table, the system runs out of memory. Any suggestions on using UDFs or lambda to so that i can circumvent the memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [GraphX](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#:%7E:text=GraphX%20is%20a%20new%20component,to%20each%20vertex%20and%20edge.) it's part of spark. (Well it's actually [not written for pyspark](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3789) but it's a good tool for graph type problems.)

If you like the idea of doing graph things in pyspark checkout. [GraphFrames](https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes).

It might help you simplify your quest to solve shortest distance.

Comment: I'm actually looking to calculate actual geospatial distance like haverstine distance etc. from latitudee, longitude etc. I'm not sure if graph approach is the best one in that case as I need to compare and evaluate the minimum distance.